# Samsung One UI library for android

Tags: android

I want to write an android app that follows the samsungs one ui style guidelines:
https://developer.samsung.com/one-ui/index.html

Is there any one ui library for android that does has an implementation for e.g.

- App Bar
- Bottom Bar
- Bottom Navigation
- Buttons
- Dialog
- Lists
- Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a library on GitHub:
https://github.com/OneUIProject